# Why does querying the right most index of a composite index does not result in full table scan in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, index

Consider the following table

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table
(
    my_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    my_second_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (my_id, my_second_id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.my_table
    OWNER to my_db;
```

Querying the following

```
explain select * from my_table
where my_id = ''


explain select * from my_table
where my_second_id = ''
```

Have the following result

```
Index Scan using my_table_pkey on my_table  (cost=0.56..178699.70 rows=268 width=917)


Index Cond: (my_second_id = ''::text)


Index Scan using my_table_pkey on my_table  (cost=0.56..3544.14 rows=1142 width=917)


Index Cond: (my_id = ''::text)
```

I expect the second query that uses the right most index to do a full table scan, however I see index scan instead

Does postgres support sub index scan in composite index or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate this without going to extreme contortions, like setting enable_seqscan, enable_bitmapscan, and enable_indexonlyscan all to off.  What version are you using, what are you non-default settings, and how did you populate the data (as shown, you would get an empty table to query)?

But anyway, what it is doing here is a full index scan, using the index as a skinny table (although in your case, not much skinnier than the table itself), and applying the condition as an in-index filter.  Unfortunately, the displayed plan does not distinguish between the "Index Cond:" is being used for jump-to selectivity, versus just as an in-index filter.  But you can see the cost estimate for the query that uses it as an in-index filter is far higher (50 fold) than the one where it uses jump-to selectivity.